# Backbone.js hashed url change automatically on default value

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Problem is: When I go to step2. step2 fier well and after it for some reason "start" route active. How to solve this problem?

the scenario is following. I start from step one -> going to step 2 -> it renders step2view and immediately going to start route again. What is the reason of such behavior?

Short code below.

I have a simple page with minimum markup

```
<div id="contentHolder">
</div>
```

And also some backbone stuff

```
 var StateModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: { state: "start" }
    });

    var StepModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: { selected: [], location: null }
    });

    var WizardView = Backbone.View.extend({
        router: null,

        nestedViewModels: [],

        initialize: function () {
            this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
            this.render();
        },

        render: function () {
            switch (this.model.get("state")) {
                case "start":
                case "step1":
                    var step1 = new Step1View({el: $("#contentHolder")});
                    break;
                case "step2":
                    var step2 = new Step2View({el: $("#contentHolder")});
                    break;
                case "step3":
                    var step3 = new UploadView({el: $("#contentHolder")});
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

var Step1View = Backbone.View.extend({
       goToStep2: function(){
         router.navigate("!/step2", true);
       }
    });
    var Step2View = Backbone.View.extend({    
    });

//wizard - is a global variable
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        "": "start",
        "!/step1": "step1",
        "!/step2": "step2"
    },

    start: function () {
        wizard.model.set("state", "start");
    },

    step1: function () {
        wizard.model.set("state", "step1");
    }

    step2: function () {
        wizard.model.set("state", "step2");
    }
});
```

*Only main code listed, much auxiliary code skipped. Be sure - all object assigned. i check it multiple times.*

**UPD:** All next view render to the same place as previous one. And after Step2 renders url change to default for some reason. so instead of url...#!/step2 it change to url...# And i think this is why router fire "start". But I don't understand - what things change url.

**UPD** now it works in the following order:

1. Step1View.gotoStep2
2. Router.step2
3. WizardView.render
4. Step2View.initialize
5. Step2View.render
6. router.start

router.start obviously should not be called

Comment: In your routes you've got `this.vizardView` but your object declares `wizardView`

Comment: pleas, review question again. I make some edits. The real code is long enough and no one will be read 200 lines of code

Comment: Where does `this.vizardView` get set? Why do you still have `this.vizardView` whe the property on your router object is `wizardView`? If you're having a router problem just show us all your router code. Then if we need more we'll ask for more. But right now your router wouldn't ever work based on the code you have above.

Comment: And I'm sure you checked it, but if we can't see it we can't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I solve this at last and now dancing victory jig)))** 
The problem was coused by my Step2 button. It was a link (anchor) itself, and it has *href="#"*. so After I press on it and all scrips works fine it change my url to a.href value. Thats was why default url applied